# Flask - Check database against string

Tags: python, sql, flask

Code:

```
userExists = g.db.execute('SELECT username FROM users WHERE username = ?', [request.form['usr']])

if request.form['usr'] == userExists:
    error = 'Username already exists.'
```

Hopefully the code is self-explanatory.  If not, I want a registering user to have his name checked against the database.  The username must be unique so if the information entered into the form (request.form['usr']) is equal to the result of the SQL query saved to the userExists variable then an error should be thrown (error = 'Username already exists.').

Is the query returning the number of rows matching username instead of the value of username?  Or is the logic just incorrect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this by defining the `username` as an unique key when creating table. Then put the `INSERT` into a `try ... catch ...` block. If the username exists, an exception will be thrown.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are using sqlite3 as indicated by the use of *g.db.execute* and that you have maintained a unique index on the username column since when it was created you could do something like:

```
username = request.form['usr']
print "Attempting to insert username = %s" %username
try:
    g.db.execute("insert into users(username) values('%s')" %username)
except sqlite3.IntegrityError:
    print 'Username %s is already in database' %username
    g.db.rollback()
except:
    g.db.rollback()
    #Handle other errors as desired. 
finally:
    g.db.commit()

g.db.close()
```

Unfortunately, you cannot alter a table to add unique indices or primary keys. But if you are still in design, this should work.

Comment: Why does the second except not have () after rollback?  And why do you even need the second except.

Comment: Syntax error, corrected. It really is a matter of preference. Given that the code is committed in the finally block one may want to ensure that none of the events leading to error conditions caught in the except blocks were preceded by a database modification. It is a good practice when the try block contains more database interaction code than what is in this example. The second except block is to handle errors distinct from the unique constraint violation.